# Abrir HTML via asset

Tags: java, android

Como eu faço pra abrir html via asset?
Tou fazendo meu aplicativo de editor de texto, preciso muito aprender abrir html via asset.

Answer (score 1):

Há duas formas bem simples. Antes de mais nada, precisamos criar o elemento *WebView* no *XML*, por exemplo:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

No arquivo *Java*, precisamos instanciar este elemento:

```
WebView navegador = findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

Feito isso, vamos as formas de como carregar um arquivo da pasta *assets*:

**1.** Basta criar um arquivo na pasta `src/main/assets`, por exemplo `codigo.html` e dentro deste arquivo, basta adicionar seu código *HTML*. Para carregar o arquivo na *WebView* através do método `loadUrl`, por exemplo:

```
navegador.loadUrl( "file:///android_asset/codigo.html" );
```

---

**2.** Uma outra forma é utilizar o método `loadData` do *WebView*, para isso devemos usar `getAssets().open("codigo.html");`, por exemplo:

```
try {
    WebView navegador = findViewById(R.id.webView);

    InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("codigo.html"));
    StringBuilder codigo = new StringBuilder();
    char[] b = new char[1024];

    while (inputStream.read(b) != -1) {
        codigo.append(b);
    }

    navegador.loadData(codigo.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8");

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```